# Xdebug with PhpStorm stops working when assigning an URL for Symfony debug server

Tags: symfony, azure-active-directory, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm developing a Symfony PHP Application which uses Azure Active Directory authentication. I'm using PhpStorm on Windows 10 as my IDE.

Azure Active Directory requires me to register a redirect URL but doesn't allow it to be http://127.0.0.1:8000 so I had to register http://localhost:8000

For that reason, in PhpStorm, I had to change my Run/Debug Configuration in order to change `bin\console` arguments from `server:run` to `server:run localhost:8000`.

But since I did that, PhpStorm no longer stops at my assigned breakpoints, as if it weren't listening to Xdebug's connections, although it is set to do so. I'm sure the problem is the new URL, because when I rolled back my change, it came back to normal.

I know the question is rather specific.

Comment: 1) OS? 2) Collect and check Xdebug log -- where it tries to connect 3) PhpStorm Xdebug related settings / Server entry config. Right now it could be that IPv6 is used instead of IPv4 ... (`127.0.0.1` is IPv4 .. but `localhost` may get resolved into IPv6 first...)

Comment: `localhost:8000` and  `127.0.0.1:8000` are basically the same thing. If you check the docs, you'll see that [not passing arguments is equivalent of doing server:run localhost:8000](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html#starting-the-web-server). So I think something else is amiss in your setup.

Comment: @LazyOne, thanks for the edit. I'm using Windows.

Comment: @yivi, thanks, I understand `localhost:8000` resolves to `127.0.0.1:8000`, but the fact is, when I run `php bin/console server:run` it will show the message `[OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000` and XDebug works. When I run `php bin/console server:run localhost:8000` it will show the message `[OK] Server listening on http://localhost:8000` and XDebug doesn't work.

Comment: 1) Check if Xdebug is enabled (just in case; via `phpinfo()` on where it does not work) 2) Collect Xdebug log -- it should tell if it tries to connect or not 3) place `xdebug_break();` in your code and see if it will trigger anything. It's juts not clear if Xdebug doe snot work in IDE .. or if it's not trying to debug at all...